# Laravel `Item` has many, return only if ALL are in the past

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my project, a `hire` can have many `hire_days`. Each `hire_day` is has a `start` and `end` timestamp.
I want to create a query where it will return only the hires where ALL of it's associated `hire_day.end` times are in the past.
So far, my query:

```
$hires = Hires::join('hires_days', function ($join) {
            $join->on('hire_id', '=', 'hires.id');
        })
        ->select('hires.id', 'hires.account_id', 'hires.job_number', 'hires.site_id', \DB::raw('MAX(end) AS end'))
        ->orderBy('hires_days.end', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('hires.id')
        ->paginate(10);
```

This will return `hires` if at least one of their `hire_days` is in the past, ignoring the fact that there are some associated `hire_days` still in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is to add to your query:

`->having('end', '<', time())`

Comment: Strangely it says `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'end' in 'having clause'` - even though it's ordering by that column!

Comment: Edit - Actually when I remove `paginate()` and use `get()`, it works. I suppose there's a bug within Laravel then